Webassembly runs much slowly than pure JavaScript function
im newly in webassembly. i just try it by writing a fuction to filter the array of objects base on some criterias and return an array of id. i run this function in and measure execution time. Surprisingly, Webassembly run slowly 10 times than JS.
My filter JS functon:
function filter(array: Obj[], criteria: Filter, additionalArr: number[]){
//Filter....
}

C++ file like this:
#include<emscripten/bind.h>
#include<emscripten/val.h>

struct Filter {
  vector<int> f1;
  vector<int> f2;
  vector<string> f3;

  Filter(): f1({}), f2({}), f3({}) {}

  Filter(vector<int> f1, vector<int> f2, vector<string> f3) : 
   f1(f1), f2(f2), f3(f3) {}
};

struct Obj {
  int p1;
  int p2;
  string p3;

  Obj (): p1(0), p2(0), p3("") {}

  Obj (int p1, int p2, string p3) : 
   p1(p1), p2(p2), f3(p3) {}
}

Obj processObj(emscripten::val jsObj){
  Obj wasmObj = new Obj();
  wasmObj.p1 = jsObj["p1"].as<int>();
  wasmObj.p2 = jsObj["p2"].as<int>();
  wasmObj.p3 = jsObj["p3"].as<string>();
  
  return wasmObj;
}

Filter processFilter(emscripten::val jsFilter){
 //Similar to processObj
}

bool filterOneObj(Obj obj, Filter criterias, vector<int> additionalArr) {
 //Filter one obj base on criterias and additionalArr
}

emscripten::val wasmFilter(emscripten::val objJS, emscripten::val criteriaJS, emscripten:: val additionalArrJS) {
   vector<int> result;
   Filter wasmFilter = processFilter(criteriaJS);
   for(size_t i = 0; i < objJS["length"].as<size_t>(); i++) {
      if(filterOneObj()) result.push_back(objJS[i]["p1"].as<int>());
   }
   return val::array(result);
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(module) {
  class_<Filter>("WasmFilter")
    .constructor<vector<int>,
                vector<int>,
                vector<string>>
   .property("f1", &Filter::f1)
   .property("f2", &Filter::f2)
   .property("f3", &Filter::f3)

  class_<Obj>("WasmObj")...//similar to Filter

  emscripten::register_vector<int>("IntList");

  emscripten::register_vector<Obj>("ObjList");

  emscripten::function("wasmFilter", &wasmFilter);
}

Compile C++ to wasm using this command:
emcc -lembind -Iinclude -s WASM= -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s ENVIRONMENT=web filter.cpp -o filter.js

I run this function with large array (100.000) and the result is JS execution time about 1s and call wasmFilter from JS about 10s.
I don't know which part in c++ file make wasm run much slowly. Is it because of using embind???
I read many articles that show Webassembly is faster than Js.
I also know that in some cases Webassembly is not effecient. But in my case, Webassembly runs much slowly.
Why? And is there any efective way to passing object and array between JS and C++??

At a minimum, you should add -O3 to emcc flags.

You are not compiling/building the C++ code with optimizations turned on.  Instead you are running an unoptimized "debug" build.

Just guessing, but the JS algorithm may be just better than the C++ one. It may be using some (highly optimized) internal function. Yours may be slower because of the dynamic allocation of the result array or because of some data type conversions.

No point in making performance measurements of non-optimized code.

So many copies in your C++ code... passing by const reference should be better.

struct Obj {...}; -- Obj processObj(emscripten::val jsObj){ Obj wasmObj = new Obj(); -- There is no way this could have compiled without error.  In C++, new returns a pointer, not an object.  If anything, that entire processObj function could have been { return { jsObj["p1"].as<int>(), jsObj["p2"].as<int>(), jsObj["p3"].as<string>() } };

After, I add -O3 to emcc but wasm still run slowly than js one.

Obj processObj(emscripten::val jsObj) --> Obj processObj(const emscripten::val& jsObj).  As mentioned in a previous comment, you should be passing these objects by (const) reference, not by value.  When you pass by value, you are creating a whole new temporary copy of the parameter.  Doing this slows down the code.  Then you still haven't explained how that code I mentioned could possibly compile, with new returning a pointer, but you are assigning it to a non-pointer type.  This is an obvious typo, or your code is not exactly as what you are presenting here.

@PaulMcKenzie oh, thank you (Im not familiar with c++). passing by reference makes my wasm function faster. Now, wasm is 2 times slower than js. I think its reasonable because i pass very large array of object from js to c++

As many other people have pointed out, there are various issues with your C++ code that make you lose some performance. If you fix them, you should probably come close to plain JavaScript.
However, if your main objective is performance, you have absolutely nothing to gain from WASM. There are very rare cases in which WASM can actually be faster. You should study V8 performance optimization techniques and simply stick to that.
WASM is not about performance. WASM is about compatibility and portability of existing C++ software to the web.
